# Hide shipping method name and title from frontend

Tags: magento-1.7, checkout, shipping

In front end on checkout page in shipment section shipping methods and name appears in bracket along with shipping and handling.

Now it looks like
*Shipping & Handling (title - method name): 5$*

I want look like 
*Shipping & Handling: 5$*

Kindly help..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can override the method: `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Shipping::fetch()`.
Inside it, there is this piece of code:

```
$title = Mage::helper('sales')->__('Shipping & Handling');
if ($address->getShippingDescription()) {
    $title .= ' (' . $address->getShippingDescription() . ')';
}
```

You can comment out the if statement and not show the shipping description.

Comment: is there any other way to do it?
may be template!

Comment: You can try to modify this template: `tax/checkout/shipping.phtml`  and use a regular expression to remove what is inside '(..)' from `<?php echo $this->getTotal()->getTitle() ?> `. But I really suggest the method in the answer. It's cleaner.

Comment: Thanks man. I will override method rather than using regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do that by going to System->Configuration->Shipping Method and delete the description text.

it won't show the description text. You do not need to edit any code for this.

Comment: The shipping description is generated like this `$shippingDescription = $rate->getCarrierTitle() . ' - ' . $rate->getMethodTitle()`. if you delete the titles of the carier and the methods you will still see ' - ' in the description and you will confuse the customers because they will not see a label on the shipping method step of the checkout.

Comment: Indeed Marius. 

You are right!

Answer (score 0):

You can hide shipping method from front end with observer, write this code in `config.xml`

```
<frontend>
<events>
    <sales_quote_collect_totals_before>
        <observers>
            <frontend_shipping_rates_sales_quote_collect_totals_before>
                <class>yourmodule/observer</class>
                <method>hideShippingMethods</method>                    
            </frontend_shipping_rates_sales_quote_collect_totals_before>
        </observers>                
    </sales_quote_collect_totals_before>
</events>
```

Second in `Observer.php` use this code

```
public function hideShippingMethods( Varien_Event_Observer $observer )
{
    if (Mage::getDesign()->getArea() ===   Mage_Core_Model_App_Area::AREA_FRONTEND)
    {
        $quote              = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();
        $store              = Mage::app()->getStore($quote->getStoreId());
        $carriers           = Mage::getStoreConfig('carriers', $store);

        $hiddenMethodCode   = 'freeshipping'; 

        foreach ($carriers as $carrierCode => $carrierConfig) 
        {
            if( $carrierCode ==  $hiddenMethodCode )
            {
                $store->setConfig("carriers/{$carrierCode}/active", '0');
            }
        }
}
 }
```